# need help on squid url_rewrite_program

Tags: squid

I'm writing a url_rewrite_program that rewrite a url "req_url"
to
"http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/some-cgi?url=req_url".

The cgi will get the resource at req_url, do some processing and return the result to Squid which then returns the result to the original requester. To avoid rewrite loop,  I disable the url rewrite for the requests issued by the localhost by doing this:

acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32

acl myip src my-proxy-ip   #repalced with the real ip of my proxy

url_rewrite_access deny localhost

url_rewrite_access deny myip

Now, the machine running Squid can get the resource at req_url without any problem, because I disabled the rewrite for the localhost. But any other machine cannot get the resource at req_url. It hangs.

It seems that my rewrite program has some problem. Basically, it assumes that the input given by Squid (version 3.1) has the following form:

"req_url[SP]ip ..."        //SP means space

and returns

"http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/some-cgi?url=req_url[newline]"

I'm wondering what's the problem of this program. By the way, the cgi runs flawlessly.